# Get row info from table using razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am making an ASP.NET MVC app and I currently have a table:

```
|ID|first name|surname|
 1   bob        smith   Select <- (clickable)
```

I am currently getting data in my controller and passing it to the view in a ViewBag then using razor to create the table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>surname</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach (var name in ViewBag.names)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@name.Id</td>
            <td>@name.firstname</td>
            <td>@name.surname</td>
            <td>Select</td> <- shall make this clickable
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Is there a way to get information from the table (when I click the select button). Ideally just the Id for that row.

I am also trying to avoid javascript

The aim is to call an actionResult method in my controller passing in the id as a parameter

```
 public ActionResult Login(int id)
    {
// do stuff
}
```

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you actually trying to do, perform an action when the button for that row is clicked, based on the ID of that row?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @alex I would like to call an actionResult method in my controller passing in the id as a parameter

Comment: @Shoe added some code for you

Comment: @BrianPeach Presuming I understand the question correctly, my proposed solution should fulfil the criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your clickable element using the [MVC HTML helper ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) (and various other helpers), specifically [the one that accepts routeValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), and use the ID there. MVC will then generate the URL for you.

[This tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view) on the asp.net site shows you in context how these work

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "Login", new { id=name.Id })
```

The previous page in the tutorial explains how to scaffold and create basic CRUD operations. I'd highly suggest reading through the documentation.